# Java AES 256 password based encryption decryption

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

Obviously not a cryptography expert, but after some reading here and github and came up with this implementation. Could someone with better knowledge kindly tell me if my implementation is safe ? many thanks.

My use case :

- encrypting some properties key. When the service starts, the password is read from an ENV variable
- The key is derived from the password. Key is unique per property key. Key is salted, and salt is used during decryption when the key is derived again from the password
- The code will be published on github, it's critical that any properties are almost impossible to decrypt

Any suggestions appreciated :-)

```
    public class SunJceCryptoService implements CryptoService {

    private static final int KEY_DERIVATION_ITERATION = 5_000_000;
    private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;

    private static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "SunJCE";
    private static final String KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
    private static final String SECURE_RANDOM_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String CIPHER_MODE = "AES_256/GCM/NoPadding";
    private static final String PAYLOAD_SEPARATOR = " ";

    private final String password;

    public SunJceCryptoService(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String encrypt(final String clearText) {

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_MODE, PROVIDER_NAME);
            final byte[] salt = generateSalt();
            final byte[] iv = new byte[12];
            SecureRandom.getInstance(SECURE_RANDOM_ALGORITHM).nextBytes(iv);
            GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, deriveSecretKey(password, salt), gcmParameterSpec);

            final byte[] aad = new byte[12];
            SecureRandom.getInstance(SECURE_RANDOM_ALGORITHM).nextBytes(aad);
            cipher.updateAAD(aad);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(clearText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(iv), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + PAYLOAD_SEPARATOR +
                    new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(aad), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + PAYLOAD_SEPARATOR +
                    new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedBytes), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + PAYLOAD_SEPARATOR +
                    new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(salt), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoServiceException();
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(final String encryptedPayload) {

        try {
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_MODE, PROVIDER_NAME);
            final String[] sections = encryptedPayload.split(PAYLOAD_SEPARATOR);
            final byte[] iv = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sections[0]);
            final byte[] aad = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sections[1]);
            final byte[] encryptedText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sections[2]);
            final byte[] salt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sections[3]);

            GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, deriveSecretKey(password, salt), gcmParameterSpec);
            cipher.updateAAD(aad);

            return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedText));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoServiceException();
        }
    }

    public SecretKey deriveSecretKey(String password, byte[] salt) {
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory;
        try {
            secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM);

            return new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyFactory
                    .generateSecret(
                            new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(),
                                    salt,
                                    KEY_DERIVATION_ITERATION,
                                    KEY_LENGTH)
                    ).getEncoded(),
                    CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoServiceException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ideally, the salt value is a random (or pseudorandom) string of the length HashLen
     */
    public byte[] generateSalt() {
        try {
            byte salt[] = new byte[KEY_LENGTH / 8];
            SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance(SECURE_RANDOM_ALGORITHM);
            //SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
            secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
            return salt;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoServiceException();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I regard the questions "Is my implementation safe" or "is my implementation secure" as too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe CodeReview.

Comment: @LukePark Codereview is for working pieces of code. With additional comments and requirements the code probably would be a good fit for CodeReview.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I'm more interested in a crypto review than a code review. May I rephrase my question as: would this be safe to share publicly `iv`, `aad`,`encrypted string`, and `salt` assuming that aes256 implementation is correclty done ?